# Returning a table from a cursor

Tags: postgresql, types, cursor, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

I have a function that returns a table of calculated values based on a customer id. I need to get values for all customers; I made a cursor but I can't make it return the set.

Customer table:

```
id    name
----  ----
CN102 Dude
CN103 Guy
CN104 Mate
```

Function:

```
SELECT * FROM get_custom_fields('CN104');

name  field_value
----  -----
POP    9
Z44   blue
POP    19
```

Please note there could be multiple rows with the same name.
This is my cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_cursor () 
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    v_customer_rec RECORD;
    v_pop RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR v_customer_rec IN SELECT ucn FROM customer LOOP
        SELECT INTO v_pop field_value from get_custom_fields(v_customer_rec.ucn) where custom_field='POP';
        RAISE NOTICE 'Customer % Value %', v_customer_rec.ucn,v_pop;
        --   RETURN QUERY select field_value from get_custom_fields(v_customer_rec.ucn) where custom_field='POP';
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This returns:

```
db=# select my_cursor();
NOTICE:  Customer CN102 Value (5)
NOTICE:  Customer CN103 Value (12)
NOTICE:  Customer CN104 Value (9)
NOTICE:  Customer CN104 Value (19)
 my_cursor 
-------------
(0 rows)
```

So I know it *should* work. But if use `RETURN QUERY` (as commented in the code) I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "my_cursor" line 9 at RETURN QUERY
> ```

How can I make it return the values in a table or set?

I'm trying to get:

```
ucn   field_value
----- -----------
CN102 5
CN103 12
CN104 9
CN104 19
```

Comment: Where is the function `active_customers()` defined?

Comment: I didn't include it because it just spits out the customer table at the top. Just pretend its a select * from customer.

Comment: Then you should use `select * from customer` in your question. Please fix it, so it makes sense to the general public, not just to you. Use `edit` right under your question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (simplified) function could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_cursor() 
  RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ucn text;
BEGIN

FOR _ucn IN
    SELECT ucn FROM customer
LOOP
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT *
    FROM   get_custom_fields(_ucn)
    WHERE  name = 'POP';
END LOOP;

RETURN;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am assuming  data type `text` for `ucn` here.

But really, you should **define the `RETURN` type**, to avoid having to provide a column definition list with every call. If you just want the column `field_value`, and it is type `text`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_cursor() 
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ucn text;
BEGIN

FOR _ucn IN
    SELECT ucn FROM customer
LOOP
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT field_value
    FROM   get_custom_fields(_ucn)
    WHERE  name = 'POP';
END LOOP;

RETURN;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or use [**`RETURNS TABLE()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) for multiple columns per row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_cursor() 
  RETURNS TABLE(ucn text, field_value text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ucn text;
BEGIN

FOR _ucn IN
    SELECT c.ucn FROM customer c
LOOP
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT g.ucn, g.field_value
    FROM   get_custom_fields(_ucn) g
    WHERE  g.name = 'POP';
END LOOP;

RETURN;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Be aware that the columns of the RETURN type are visible in the function body. Table-qualify columns of the same name to avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: Thank you very much, the second version works perfectly. I tried the first one but I can't make it return a table.

The problem is that some customer will have more than one value for POP (question edited) so output should be something like:

    ucn   field_vaule
    ----- -----------
    CN102 5
    CN103 12
    CN103 66
    CN104 9

Comment: @RaiderofthelostBBS: I added another one to cover that.

Comment: @RaiderofthelostBBS: About formatting: Click the help link under [Add Comment] while writing one for help. Or look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). :)